# How to get the Worksheet ID from a Google Spreadsheet with python?

Tags: python, xml, gdata, gspread

I'd like to identify a method to attain the Worksheet ID within the URL for each of the worksheets within a Google Spreadsheet Workbook. For example, the worksheet id for 'sheet2' of [this workbook](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yd8qTYjRns4_OT8PbsZzH0zajvzguKS79dq6j--hnTs/edit#gid=1244369280) is '1244369280' , since it's url is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yd8qTYjRns4_OT8PbsZzH0zajvzguKS79dq6j--hnTs/edit#gid=1244369280

One method I've found is to pull the XML of a Google Spreadsheet, since according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23609688/how-to-convert-from-gid-to-od-worksheet-id-in-new-google-spreadsheets/25436149#25436149), the only way to get the Worksheet ID is to stream down the XML of a worksheet, but the example is in Javascript and I need to do this in Python

This is the Javascript Code that I'd like to execute in Python:

```
  Dim worksheetFeed As WorksheetFeed
  Dim query As WorksheetQuery
  Dim worksheet As WorksheetEntry
  Dim output As New MemoryStream
  Dim xml As String
  Dim gid As String = String.Empty

  Try
    _service = New Spreadsheets.SpreadsheetsService("ServiceName")
    _service.setUserCredentials(UserId, Password)
    query = New WorksheetQuery(feedUrl)
    worksheetFeed = _service.Query(query)
    worksheet = worksheetFeed.Entries(0)

    ' Save worksheet feed to memory stream so we can 
    ' get the xml returned from the feed url and look for
    ' the gid.  Gid allows us to download the specific worksheet tab
    Using output
      worksheet.SaveToXml(output)
    End Using

    xml = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(output.ToArray())
```

It seems that the best way to get the XML from a Google Spreadsheet is using Gdata, so I've downloaded GData and tried [the Google Spreadsheet example](https://github.com/google/gdata-python-client/blob/master/samples/spreadsheets/spreadsheetExample.py) with my credentials.

See below

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#
# Copyright (C) 2007 Google Inc.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.


__author__ = 'api.laurabeth@gmail.com (Laura Beth Lincoln)'


try:
  from xml.etree import ElementTree
except ImportError:
  from elementtree import ElementTree
import gdata.spreadsheet.service
import gdata.service
import atom.service
import gdata.spreadsheet
import atom
import getopt
import sys
import string


class SimpleCRUD:

  def __init__(self, email, password):
    self.gd_client = gdata.spreadsheet.service.SpreadsheetsService()
    self.gd_client.email = 'chris@curalate.com'
    self.gd_client.password = 'jkjkdioerzumawya'
    self.gd_client.source = 'Spreadsheets GData Sample'
    self.gd_client.ProgrammaticLogin()
    self.curr_key = ''
    self.curr_wksht_id = ''
    self.list_feed = None

  def _PromptForSpreadsheet(self):
    # Get the list of spreadsheets
    feed = self.gd_client.GetSpreadsheetsFeed()
    self._PrintFeed(feed)
    input = raw_input('\nSelection: ')
    id_parts = feed.entry[string.atoi(input)].id.text.split('/')
    self.curr_key = id_parts[len(id_parts) - 1]

  def _PromptForWorksheet(self):
    # Get the list of worksheets
    feed = self.gd_client.GetWorksheetsFeed(self.curr_key)
    self._PrintFeed(feed)
    input = raw_input('\nSelection: ')
    id_parts = feed.entry[string.atoi(input)].id.text.split('/')
    self.curr_wksht_id = id_parts[len(id_parts) - 1]

  def _PromptForCellsAction(self):
    print ('dump\n'
           'update {row} {col} {input_value}\n'
           '\n')
    input = raw_input('Command: ')
    command = input.split(' ', 1)
    if command[0] == 'dump':
      self._CellsGetAction()
    elif command[0] == 'update':
      parsed = command[1].split(' ', 2)
      if len(parsed) == 3:
        self._CellsUpdateAction(parsed[0], parsed[1], parsed[2])
      else:
        self._CellsUpdateAction(parsed[0], parsed[1], '')
    else:
      self._InvalidCommandError(input)

  def _PromptForListAction(self):
    print ('dump\n'
           'insert {row_data} (example: insert label=content)\n'
           'update {row_index} {row_data}\n'
           'delete {row_index}\n'
           'Note: No uppercase letters in column names!\n'
           '\n')
    input = raw_input('Command: ')
    command = input.split(' ' , 1)
    if command[0] == 'dump':
      self._ListGetAction()
    elif command[0] == 'insert':
      self._ListInsertAction(command[1])
    elif command[0] == 'update':
      parsed = command[1].split(' ', 1)
      self._ListUpdateAction(parsed[0], parsed[1])
    elif command[0] == 'delete':
      self._ListDeleteAction(command[1])
    else:
      self._InvalidCommandError(input)

  def _CellsGetAction(self):
    # Get the feed of cells
    feed = self.gd_client.GetCellsFeed(self.curr_key, self.curr_wksht_id)
    self._PrintFeed(feed)

  def _CellsUpdateAction(self, row, col, inputValue):
    entry = self.gd_client.UpdateCell(row=row, col=col, inputValue=inputValue, 
        key=self.curr_key, wksht_id=self.curr_wksht_id)
    if isinstance(entry, gdata.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetsCell):
      print 'Updated!'

  def _ListGetAction(self):
    # Get the list feed
    self.list_feed = self.gd_client.GetListFeed(self.curr_key, self.curr_wksht_id)
    self._PrintFeed(self.list_feed)

  def _ListInsertAction(self, row_data):
    entry = self.gd_client.InsertRow(self._StringToDictionary(row_data), 
        self.curr_key, self.curr_wksht_id)
    if isinstance(entry, gdata.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetsList):
      print 'Inserted!'

  def _ListUpdateAction(self, index, row_data):
    self.list_feed = self.gd_client.GetListFeed(self.curr_key, self.curr_wksht_id)
    entry = self.gd_client.UpdateRow(
        self.list_feed.entry[string.atoi(index)], 
        self._StringToDictionary(row_data))
    if isinstance(entry, gdata.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetsList):
      print 'Updated!'

  def _ListDeleteAction(self, index):
    self.list_feed = self.gd_client.GetListFeed(self.curr_key, self.curr_wksht_id)
    self.gd_client.DeleteRow(self.list_feed.entry[string.atoi(index)])
    print 'Deleted!'

  def _StringToDictionary(self, row_data):
    dict = {}
    for param in row_data.split():
      temp = param.split('=')
      dict[temp[0]] = temp[1]
    return dict

  def _PrintFeed(self, feed):
    for i, entry in enumerate(feed.entry):
      if isinstance(feed, gdata.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetsCellsFeed):
        print '%s %s\n' % (entry.title.text, entry.content.text)
      elif isinstance(feed, gdata.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetsListFeed):
        print '%s %s %s' % (i, entry.title.text, entry.content.text)
        # Print this row's value for each column (the custom dictionary is
        # built using the gsx: elements in the entry.)
        print 'Contents:'
        for key in entry.custom:  
          print '  %s: %s' % (key, entry.custom[key].text) 
        print '\n',
      else:
        print '%s %s\n' % (i, entry.title.text)

  def _InvalidCommandError(self, input):
    print 'Invalid input: %s\n' % (input)

  def Run(self):
    self._PromptForSpreadsheet()
    self._PromptForWorksheet()
    input = raw_input('cells or list? ')
    if input == 'cells':
      while True:
        self._PromptForCellsAction()
    elif input == 'list':
      while True:
        self._PromptForListAction()


def main():
  # parse command line options
  try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "", ["user=", "pw="])
  except getopt.error, msg:
    print 'python spreadsheetExample.py --user [username] --pw [password] '
    sys.exit(2)

  user = 'fake@gmail.com'
  pw = 'fakepassword'
  key = ''
  # Process options
  for o, a in opts:
    if o == "--user":
      user = a
    elif o == "--pw":
      pw = a

  if user == '' or pw == '':
    print 'python spreadsheetExample.py --user [username] --pw [password] '
    sys.exit(2)

  sample = SimpleCRUD(user, pw)
  sample.Run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

However this returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Chris/Desktop/gdata_test.py", line 200, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/Chris/Desktop/gdata_test.py", line 196, in main
    sample.Run()
  File "/Users/Chris/Desktop/gdata_test.py", line 162, in Run
    self._PromptForSpreadsheet()
  File "/Users/Chris/Desktop/gdata_test.py", line 49, in _PromptForSpreadsheet
    feed = self.gd_client.GetSpreadsheetsFeed()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gdata/spreadsheet/service.py", line 99, in GetSpreadsheetsFeed
    converter=gdata.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetsSpreadsheetsFeedFromString)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gdata/service.py", line 1074, in Get
    return converter(result_body)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gdata/spreadsheet/__init__.py", line 395, in SpreadsheetsSpreadsheetsFeedFromString
    xml_string)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/atom/__init__.py", line 93, in optional_warn_function
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/atom/__init__.py", line 127, in CreateClassFromXMLString
    tree = ElementTree.fromstring(xml_string)
  File "<string>", line 125, in XML
cElementTree.ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0
[Finished in 0.3s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/Chris/Desktop/gdata_test.py"]
[dir: /Users/Chris/Desktop]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

I should also mention that I've been using Gspread as a method to interact with Google Spreadsheets, but when I run the below code, I get the gid, but I need to have the worksheet id.

```
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
sh = gc.open_by_url('google_spreadsheet_url')
sh.get_id_fields() 
>> {'spreadsheet_id': '1BgCEn-3Nor7UxOEPwD-qv8qXe7CaveJBrn9_Lcpo4W4','worksheet_id': 'oqitk0d'}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the `self.gd_client.ProgrammaticLogin()` call - this is causing the major problem since it uses the "ClientLogin" authorization method which was first deprecated and later [removed on April 20, 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30471268/did-clientlogin-api-shut-down).

I would actually look into the more fresh and actively developed [`gspread`](https://github.com/burnash/gspread) module instead.

---

Here is a, somewhat insane, example demonstrating how to extract the actual "gid" value for a given spreadsheet and worksheet name. Note that you would first need to [generate the JSON file with the OAuth credentials](http://gspread.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth2.html) (I'm assuming you've already done that).

The code (added comments that would hopefully help to understand it):

```
import urlparse
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

SPREADSHEET_NAME = 'My Test Spreadsheet'
WORKSHEET_NAME = "Sheet2"

PATH_TO_JSON_KEYFILE = '/path/to/json/key/file.json'
NAMESPACES = {'ns0': 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'}
SCOPES = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']

# log in
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(PATH_TO_JSON_KEYFILE, SCOPES)
gss_client = gspread.authorize(credentials)

# open spreadsheet
gss = gss_client.open(SPREADSHEET_NAME)

# extract the full feed url
root = gss._feed_entry
full_feed_url = next(elm.attrib["href"] for elm in root.findall("ns0:link", namespaces=NAMESPACES) if "full" in elm.attrib["href"])

# get the feed and extract the gid value for a given sheet name
response = gss_client.session.get(full_feed_url)
root = ET.fromstring(response.content)
sheet_entry = next(elm for elm in root.findall("ns0:entry", namespaces=NAMESPACES)
                   if elm.find("ns0:title", namespaces=NAMESPACES).text == WORKSHEET_NAME)
link = next(elm.attrib["href"] for elm in sheet_entry.findall("ns0:link", namespaces=NAMESPACES)
            if "gid=" in elm.attrib["href"])

# extract "gid" from URL
gid = urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(link).query)["gid"][0]
print(gid)
```

---

It also looks like there is a way to convert the worksheet ID to a gid value, see:

- [How to convert Google spreadsheet's worksheet string id to integer index (GID)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11290337/how-to-convert-google-spreadsheets-worksheet-string-id-to-integer-index-gid)

Comment: I actually use gspread and have the most recent version, and gspread is one of the roots of my issue! I did the following using gspread: gc.open_by_url(title).worksheet(sheet_title).get_id_fields(), and that returns this: {'spreadsheet_id': '1BgCEn-3Nor7UxOEPwD-qv8qXe7CaveJBrn9_Lcpo4W4','worksheet_id': 'oqitk0d'}. That worksheet_id is not the worksheet_id within the URL, which is what I need. As a result, I need to resort to pulling XML data. I've searched all through the gspread module and have not been able to find how to pull the XML from gspread, but that would be the upmost ideal scenario

Comment: @Chris okay, got it, let me experiment with gspread and see if we can get to the ws id.

Comment: Got the following error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Chris/Desktop/gspread_test.py", line 35, in <module>
    root = ET.fromstring(response.content)
AttributeError: HTTPResponse instance has no attribute 'content'
[Finished in 3.3s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/Chris/Desktop/gspread_test.py"]
[dir: /Users/Chris/Desktop]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]

Comment: @Chris please try with upgrading `gspread`: `pip install --upgrade gspread`. And, if that does not work, do: `pip install --upgrade requests`.

Comment: It works great, but at times I get this error:   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/retrying.py", line 49, in wrapped_f
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/retrying.py", line 212, in call
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/retrying.py", line 247, in get
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/retrying.py", line 200, in call
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Shippy/API/gspread_api.py", line 77, in gid_from_gspread
    sheet_entry = next(elm for elm in root.findall("ns0:entry", namespaces=NAMESPACES)
StopIteration

Comment: @Chris yeah, the code misses a good error handling. You should probably wrap the relevant parts into try except blocks and determine the reasons for the errors. In this case, it looks like the XML feed does not contain the relevant entry.

Answer (score 0):

**Jan 2017**

You can use the new google spreadsheet api v4. You could take look at [pygsheets](https://github.com/nithinmurali/pygsheets) library which uses api v4.

```
import pygsheets

#authorize the pygsheets
gc = pygsheets.authorize()

#open the spreadsheet
sh = gc.open('my new ssheet')

# get the worksheet and its id    
print sh.worksheet_by_title("my test sheet").id
```

Answer (score 0):

this seems to work for me using gspread

given a spreadsheet's worksheet url named 'mysheet1' that looks like this:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxf435454xxkjkjk23232325/edit#gid=645031900
```

this could be use to retrieve the gid value (aka: worksheet id or sheetid)

```
ss_key = xxxxxf435454xxkjkjk23232325
wks_name = mysheet1
gc.open_by_key('xxxxxf435454xxkjkjk23232325').worksheet('mysheet1').id
```

result:

```
645031900
```